# Macro Removal When Submitting Documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I edit and format large proposals and recently started working with macros to speed up the process. However, occasionally my proposal submissions have to be electronic. I am worried the file may be rejected if there are macros attached.

If I copy and paste all the text into a new Word Document after using the macros, will this remove any trace of them? All my macros are stored in a Word Template and not in normal.dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they are leaving anything in your Word document, something like "Was done via vba" or anything like that. Then creating a new Word Document with just the text copied and pasted will not copy over the macros.

You could use the macros to do this as well. Just have them open a new Document and copy and paste into it. Macros will not get copied over unless you create code to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much, but I really appreciate the confirmation!